# WSDL Basic Schema for simple login

Tags: xml, wsdl

I'm struggling to get my head around creating a basic definition for WSDL to process a simple login.

I'm creating a service that I'm calling `uQuizService`.

At the moment it is really in it's infancy, I wish to create an operation.  I have a port called `uQuizMembership` and an operation called `DoLogin` which is processed by a PHP Script.

Desired input and outputs for `DoLogin`:

- `loginRequest`: I wish for this to take a USERNAME and PASSWORD as
  strings.
- `loginResponse`: I wish to return the generated SESSION_ID as
  a string.

At the moment the input, is specified as a single string (I think :/).

I'm not sure how I specify a USERNAME and PASSWORD for the `loginRequest` input to the `DoLogin`operation.

Here's my WSDL file so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<wsdl:definitions name="uQuizSOAP"
targetNamespace="urn:uQuizSoap"
xmlns:tns="urn:uQuizSoap"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:service name="uQuizService">
    <port name="uQuizPort" binding="uQuizBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://uquiz/soap_server.php" />
    </port>
</wsdl:service>

<wsdl:portType name="uQuizMembership">
    <wsdl:operation name="DoLogin">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:loginRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:loginResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="loginResponse">
    <part name="login_session_id" type="xsd:string" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:binding name="uQuizBinding" type="tns:uQuizPortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="DoLogin">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#DoLogin" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes"
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes"
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

My Problems:

I'm not sure if the input and output definitions are correct within the `binding` as it currently stands.

I'm not sure how to change it to accept username and password strings instead of just a single string.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the WSDL you posted is not valid. In the service section, the port binding is set to `uQuizBinding` when it should be `tns:uQuizBinding`

```
<port name="uQuizPort" binding="tns:uQuizBinding">
```

while in the binding section the type attribute is set to `tns:uQuizBinding` when I think it should be `tns:uQuizMembership`

```
<wsdl:binding name="uQuizBinding" type="tns:uQuizMembership">
```

And the request is indeed specified as a single string (just the `username`) because you only defined one part for the message:

```
<wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
    <!-- this is missing -->
    <part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Fix these items and you should get requests and responses that look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:DoLogin>
         <username>...</username>
         <password>...</password>
      </urn:DoLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:DoLoginResponse>
         <login_session_id>...</login_session_id>
      </urn:DoLoginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also please be aware that **you are using RPC/encoded style** which isn't the recommended one for interoperability. See this article for some guidelines: [Which style of WSDL should I use?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) and maybe look at an working example which uses document/literal style: http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/Calculator/Version1/Calculator.asmx

You might also want to make this secure since you are doing a login operation :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, you're great! :)  I'm going to edit it all up now and see what happens.